# Join two columns of one table to the same column of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables User and task.

```
User Table                    
int id
fname
lname

Task Table
int id
int assigned_by
int assigned_to
```

assigned_by and assigned_to store the id values of the user.I have to display assigned_by and assigned_to values in the same query.

```
select u.fname+ +u.lname 
from user u,task t 
where u.id=t.assigned_by;
```

How to add u.id=t.assigned_to in the same query.

Comment: Look into ANSI style joins, they're more explicit, easier to debug, and easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the `user` table twice with different alias names

```
select CONCAT_WS(' ', u_by.fname, u_by.lname) as by_name,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', u_to.fname, u_to.lname) as to_name
from task t 
join user u_by on u_by.id = t.assigned_by
join user u_to on u_to.id = t.assigned_to
```

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit join and `concat` for string addition

```
select concat(u1.fname ,u2.lname) as assigned_by_name,
 concat(u2.fname,u2.lname) as assigned_to_name
from task t 
join user u1 on u1.id = t.assigned_by
join user u2 on u2.id = t.assigned_to
```

**Note  Avoid this old method join** `from user u,task t where u.id=t.assigned_by`